# Save image from python script to server without saving on local machine

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Is there any way to save image from python script to server with python command without saving on local machine? For example, what would be the last line in this code:

```
path = 'path/to/folder/on/server'
imfile=frame.copy() #get screenshot from my webcam
magic_function(imfile, path)
```

Maybe I can do this with paramiko library and ssh.exec_command? What should I do in this case?
I use Ubuntu 14.04 on both local and server machine and my code is in python-2.7

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't save it locally, scp it over, and then remove the local copy?

Comment: you can use `io.StringIO` or `io.ByteIO` to create file-like object in memory and then use it with function which needs file object to send it.

Comment: It might be possible for the server to become the client to your streaming service